# Choosing values in a Matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a 25x25 matrix with numeric values and I want to choose through some conditions  ! For example I want only the values from 0 to 0.2 to install them in another matrix  how can I do this ?

Comment: Is there anyway to classify them through multiple conditions ? For example resulting to something like the matrix has 120 values <0 , 130 values  in [0,0.2] , 20 values > 0.2 and so on ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you want as the output? The count? The indices? The values?

Comment: Do you want to put those values in a matrix with the same dimensions, 25x25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x<-matrix(rnorm(25*25),25,25)
which(x>0.2)  # indices where x>0.2
n<-40
h<-hist(x,breaks = seq(min(x),max(x),length.out = n+1),plot = F) # For multiple ranges and counts
h$breaks   #n+1 break points
h$count    #n counts of numbers between those breakpoints
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done with simple logical operations, see file R-intro.pdf that comes with your distribution of R, section `2.7 Index vectors; selecting and modifying subsets of a data set`.

```
set.seed(1356)    # make the results reproducible

m <- matrix(rnorm(25*25), 25)    # input matrix
i <- 0 <= m & m <= 0.2           # logical index into 'm'

# create a result matrix with the same dimensions as the input
m2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(m), ncol = ncol(m))

m2[i] <- m[i] # assign the values you want
m2

sum(i)        # count of values in [0, 0.2]
sum(m < 0)    # count of values less than zero
sum(m > 0.2)  # count of values greater than 0.2
```